# Using proc_pid_rusage in sandboxed app

Tags: macos, sandbox, appstore-sandbox

I have the following Swift code to get the current read/write speed of my hard disk:

```
fileprivate func getIOStatistics() -> (read: UInt64, written: UInt64)
{
    var read: UInt64 = 0
    var written: UInt64 = 0

    for pid in self.getAllRunning()
    {
        var usage = rusage_info_current()

        let result = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &usage)
        {
            $0.withMemoryRebound(to: (rusage_info_t?.self), capacity: 1)
            {
                proc_pid_rusage(pid, RUSAGE_INFO_CURRENT, $0)
            }
        }
        if result == 0
        {
            read += usage.ri_diskio_bytesread
            written += usage.ri_diskio_byteswritten
        }
    }

    return (read, written)
}
```

I am only able to read the data from the running process. The access to other processes is restricted, because my app is sandboxed.
Is there any temporary exception key so I can access all running processes?

The app is not published directly in the Mac App Store.